# indentation issue in html paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have 2 paragraphs as

```
<p style="color:#333333; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; margin:0; padding:0; text-align: left;">Title of para</p>

 <p style="color:#767676; line-height: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  text-align: left; margin-bottom: 1cm;  margin-top:0; padding:0;">Text</p>
```

I want to have 0 space between the 2 paragraphs but at the same time have some fixed space at the top of the 1st paragraph and at the bottom of the second paragraph.

I am creating an html email, hence the inline styles.
It works fine in some clients. But in entourage and gmail, the space between the 2 paragraphs does not go away. :(

Comment: Ahh the joys of HTML Email and inconsistent rendering across clients. I've never complained about cross browser issues after having to work with cross email client issues!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jnuHD/

I've added

```
height:12px;
```

to the first paragraph. Seems to work.

Comment: :(

How about adding !important?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that some built-in styles in Gmail are overriding the margins and paddings you've set. Have you tried adding the `!important` flag to their values and seeing if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Adding some background color shows that the problem is within the p tags not between them

http://jsfiddle.net/hs3A2/

Do you need the line height styling? if not the following reduces the spacing:

http://jsfiddle.net/UTZ8y/

You can also use line height to reduce the spacing further:
http://jsfiddle.net/99zcM/1/

Maintaining the line-height you can use positioning to adjust the "spacing":

```
<div style="position:relative;">
 <p style="line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; 
     font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; 
     margin:0; padding:0; text-align: left;">Title of para
 </p>

 <p style="color:#767676; line-height: 20px; font-size: 12px;
     font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  text-align: left; 
     margin-bottom: 1cm;  margin-top:0; padding:0;
     position:relative;top:-5px;">Text</p>
</div>
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Md9Na/

I'm not sure how well this will work on various email clients and beware of overlap

Comment: removing the line - height messes up the font formatting. I want to maintain the line-height, just want to remove the white space between the 2 paragraphs.

Comment: If you put a background color on the p elements to you get a gap between the colored backgrounds in your target clients? If not then it is not a matter of white space between the paragraphs, but an issue of how the content of the p bounding box is contained, which is why line-height works